# Accidentally removed config files from /etc/glance/

Tags: package-management

I've accidentally removed some config files from `/etc/glance` Since then i've tried to reinstall Glance thinking it'll repopulate the `/etc/glance` directory with the default config files. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
apt-get purge glance python-glanceclient
apt-get remove glance python-glanceclient
apt-get install glance python-glanceclient
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three packages that store configurations in `/etc/glance`. Make your choice:

- `glance-common`

  - `/etc/glance/glance-manage.conf`
- `glance-api`

  - `/etc/glance/glance-api-paste.ini`
  - `/etc/glance/glance-api.conf`
  - `/etc/glance/glance-cache.conf`
  - `/etc/glance/glance-scrubber.conf`
  - `/etc/glance/metadefs/glance-common-image-props.json`
- `glance-registry`

  - `/etc/glance/glance-registry-paste.ini`
  - `/etc/glance/glance-registry.conf`

But not [`python-glanceclient`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/python-glanceclient).

---

Force the creation of config files of **still installed** `glance*`-packages with:

```
dpkg -l 'glance*' | awk '/^ii/ {system("sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=\"--force-confmiss\" install --reinstall " $2)}'
```

*Command breakdown*

- `dpkg -l 'glance*' | awk '/^ii/ …'`

  Search installed packages with the name `glance*`
- `system("sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=\"--force-confmiss\" install --reinstall " $2)`

  Force the creation of missing config files

Comment: How can I retrieve those files? I've deleted the entire /etc/glance/ folder by mistake. Can I install these packages individually or download them and extract the files from the deb package?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much! The key was understanding that different processes create the different files in /etc/glance/ Previously I was trying the "--force-confmiss" option on just the glance process and it wasn't recreating any of the config files. Is there a way to identify which specific process is creating the individual files?

Comment: Yes? Great. Please accept the answer with a click on the checkmark at the left side of the answer. **;)**